# Подсветка кода в Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Помогите избавиться от выделения скобок тегов, когда курсор рядом с ними (на изображении это два прямоугольника внизу). Напрягает эта вещь, не видно в каком месте стоит он из-за подсветки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Простите, в каком месте править?

Comment: А всё, нашел в настройках по поиску параметра Brackets. Спасибо за подсказку =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Меняйте на false

```
// Выделяет соответствующие скобки при выборе одной из них.
"editor.matchBrackets": true,
```

Comment: спасибо, выручили

Comment: @inv Если ответ правильный и помог, Вы должны отметить, как правильный.

Comment: @koshe сделано.

Answer (score 0):

Ранее принятый ответ устарел. Ключ "editor.matchBrackets" теперь принимает значения "always", "near" и "never". Соответственно для отключения подсветки необходимо установить значение "never". Или можно приглушить подсветку. Для этого в файле settings.json необходимо прописать следующее:

```
{
    "editor.matchBrackets": "always",
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "editorBracketMatch.background": "#40404050",
        "editorBracketMatch.border": "#80808050"
    }
}
```

Однако эта настройка, как ни странно, отключит подсветку в html коде. В javascript, json и др. она будет активна. Вероятнее всего эти нюансы ещё не проработаны в VSC. Но если вы расширите настройку до следующего вида:

```
{
    "editor.matchBrackets": "always",
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "editorBracketMatch.background": "#40404050",
        "editorBracketMatch.border": "#80808050"
    },
    "editor.bracketPairColorization.enabled": true,
    "editor.language.colorizedBracketPairs": [
        ["[", "]"],
        ["(", ")"],
        ["{", "}"],
        ["<", ">"],
        ["<", ">"],
        ["</", ">"],
        ["<", "/>"],
    ],
}
```

То это позволит вам управлять цветом скобок и за одно активирует подсветку в html коде.